# Using React useEffect hook with rxjs mergeMap operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks, rxjs6

I'm trying to implement a data stream that has to use **inner observables**, where I use one from `mergeMap`, `concatMap` etc.

e.g.:

```
const output$$ = input$$.pipe(
    mergeMap(str => of(str).pipe(delay(10))),
    share()
  );

  output$$.subscribe(console.log);
```

This works fine when logging into console. 
But when I try to use it in React like below utilizing `useEffect` and `useState` hooks to update some text:

```
function App() {
  const input$ = new Subject<string>();
  const input$$ = input$.pipe(share());
  const output$$ = input$$.pipe(
    mergeMap(str => of(str).pipe(delay(10))),
    share()
  );

  output$$.subscribe(console.log);
  // This works

  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [output, setOutput] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = input$$.subscribe(setInput);

    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [input$$]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = output$$.subscribe(setOutput);
    // This doesn't

    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [output$$]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        onChange={event => input$.next(event.target.value)}
        value={input}
      />
      <p>{output}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

it starts acting weird/unpredictable (e.g.: sometimes the text is updated in the middle of typing, sometimes it doesn't update at all).

Things I have noticed:

- If the inner observable completes immediately/is a promise that
  resolves immediately, it works fine.
- If we print to console instead of `useEffect`, it works fine.

I believe this has to do something with the inner workings of `useEffect` and how it captures and notices outside changes, but cannot get it working.
Any help is much appreciated.

Minimal reproduction of the case:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-and-observables-1-7ygd8

Comment: `input$$` and `output$$` are being created on each render. Also, `useEffect` is depending on them, which means the effects will execute on every render.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but I found a number of problems which hopefully the following code fixes:

```jsx
function App() {
    // Create these observables only once.
    const [input$] = useState(() => new Subject<string>());
    const [input$$] = useState(() => input$.pipe(share()));
    const [output$$] = useState(() => input$$.pipe(
        mergeMap(str => of(str).pipe(delay(10))),
        share()
    ));

    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const [output, setOutput] = useState("");

    // Create the subscription to input$$ on component mount, not on every render.
    useEffect(() => {
        const subscription = input$$.subscribe(setInput);

        return () => {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        };
    }, []);

    // Create the subscription to output$$ on component mount, not on every render.
    useEffect(() => {
        const subscription = output$$.subscribe(setOutput);

        return () => {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input
                onChange={event => input$.next(event.target.value)}
                value={input}
            />
            <p>{output}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar task but the goal was to pipe and debounce the input test and execute ajax call.
The simple answer that you should init RxJS subject with arrow function in the react hook 'useState'  in order to init subject once per init.

Then you should useEffect with empty array [] in order to create a pipe once on component init.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ajax } from "rxjs/ajax";
import { debounceTime, delay, takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/internal/Subject";

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [filterChangedSubject] = useState(() => {
    // Arrow function is used to init Singleton Subject. (in a scope of a current component)
    return new Subject<string>();
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Effect that will be initialized once on a react component init. 
    // Define your pipe here.
    const subscription = filterChangedSubject
      .pipe(debounceTime(200))
      .subscribe((filter) => {
        if (!filter) {
          setLoading(false);
          setItems([]);
          return;
        }
        ajax(`https://swapi.dev/api/people?search=${filter}`)
          .pipe(
            // current running ajax is canceled on filter change.
            takeUntil(filterChangedSubject)
          )
          .subscribe(
            (results) => {
              // Set items will cause render:
              setItems(results.response.results);
            },
            () => {
              setLoading(false);
            },
            () => {
              setLoading(false);
            }
          );
      });

    return () => {
      // On Component destroy. notify takeUntil to unsubscribe from current running ajax request
      filterChangedSubject.next("");
      // unsubscribe filter change listener
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const onFilterChange = (e) => {
    // Notify subject about the filter change
    filterChangedSubject.next(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Cards
      {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      <input onChange={onFilterChange}></input>
      {items && items.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>{item.name}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```